# Wordpress WP_Post object ID doesn't match the page ID in the admin area

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting a menu in wordpress using this code

```
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Top menu', $args );
```

It returns an array with items such as below

```
[4] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 54
                [post_author] => 1
                [post_date] => 2014-02-19 20:36:53
                [post_date_gmt] => 2014-02-19 20:36:53
                [post_content] =>  
                [post_title] => 
                [post_excerpt] => 
                [post_status] => publish
                [comment_status] => open
                [ping_status] => open
                [post_password] => 
                [post_name] => 54
                [to_ping] => 
                [pinged] => 
                [post_modified] => 2014-02-19 20:36:53
                [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-02-19 20:36:53
                [post_content_filtered] => 
                [post_parent] => 7
                [guid] => http://localhost:8888/eastleigh/?p=54
                [menu_order] => 6
                [post_type] => nav_menu_item
                [post_mime_type] => 
                [comment_count] => 0
                [filter] => raw
                [db_id] => 54
                [menu_item_parent] => 27
                [object_id] => 46
                [object] => page
                [type] => post_type
                [type_label] => Page
                [url] => http://localhost:8888/eastleigh/about/menus/
                [title] => Menus
                [target] => 
                [attr_title] => 
                [description] => 
                [classes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [xfn] => 
            )
```

Seems fine, but when i go into wordpress the page doesn't have that ID , in fact no pages do ( i hovered of the pages in the admin to check the page_id).  It does however match the object_id (46)

if i dump out the get_pages array then the same page has the current id (46)

```
[5] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 46
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-02-19 20:35:25
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-02-19 20:35:25
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => Menus
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => menus
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-02-19 20:35:25
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-02-19 20:35:25
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 7
        [guid] => http://localhost:8888/eastleigh/?page_id=46
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => page
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

Could someone please explain what i'm missing here?

Thank you

Comment: check difference in post_type, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nav menu item ID isn't the same as a post (page) ID. The comparable ID you're looking for is the object_id which you've already pointed out is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Menu's are technically "Posts" They have their own ID and everything (If you don't believe me go check wp_posts table in your wp database). The difference between a menu, and a page, and a post is the little database value "post_type"

If you are looking to put a Menu into HTML use the following syntax instead:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu' => 'MENU-NAME'
        )
    );
?>
```

If you are building your own theme make sure you register this menu with your functions.php file.

Comment: Thanks Josh, that makes much more sense now.

Comment: Hope it helps, wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

A couple years late, but this result is relevant for Google so I'll just post this.

If you're using the WP Menu options from `wp-admin`, don't forget to **use the sidebar option "Pages"** or the IDs won't never match.

Later you can simply check that `$wp_query->post->ID` is the same as `$your_menu_object_item->object_id`